# Strange framerate drop with openframeworks

Tags: c++, openframeworks, frame-rate

I have a strange framerate drop with an OpenFrameworks application. At the beginning, everything works just fine at 60fps, but if the application is opened for a while (~ 2-3 minutes) the framerate drops under 10fps without any apparent reason. I don't know where to search.

Comment: You'll need to share a bit of your code, as there's **many** things that could be causing that. Some of the most likely culprits are 1) a memory leak, or 2) if you're adding more and more objects to be drawn every frame.

Comment: I don't add more and more objects to be drawn at every frame. I disabled the video grabber and the problem seems to disappear.